# is py3compat ise used in pymongo?

Tags: python, pymongo

i got this error this morning and it's bizarre!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
import handlers, os
File "G:\Mon projet\sog\handlers.py", line 5, in <module>
import gridfs
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\gridfs\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\gridfs\errors.py", line 17, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pymongo\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pymongo\connection.py", line 44, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py3compat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the problem,

it is because i've installed [bson for python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.3.3) so it dident found the file py3compat.py in the bson module, because it is not the pymongo's one that is seeked.

thank you and sorry again.

Comment: I got this too after doing "pip install bson" because I thought I needed it.  The solution was "pip uninstall bson".